# Emberjs filter content starts with blank content

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I was testing filter content for only show X number of results, I have to do it with a counter because how the adapter is returning the data.

http://jsfiddle.net/eAvET/

When you load this modified example, shows 0 data, but when you start typing on the search from, and then clear it, the results are correct.

So this line

```
if(this.get('searchTerm') === '')
```

or

```
if(this.searchTerm === '') // Refered to the controller method
```

Are not working, any idea why I have to write content inside the seach input, then clear it for make it work ? Should only return 2 results on start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at you fiddle and your problem was that you did not specify the property dependencies correctly on your `PeopleController`. I added `content.@each` and now it works.

**Why didn't it work before?**
This dependency declaration tells Ember to update this computed property every time an object is added or removed from this array. I am not absolutely sure why this happened, because the property should have worked when the content array gets swapped for a different one. I think **Ember was taking the result of your model hook and added it one by one to your ArrayController**. That would explain this behaviour.

```
App.PeopleController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
    searchTerm: '',

    filteredContent: function() {
        var people = this.get('content');
        var search = this.get('searchTerm').toLowerCase();
        if(this.searchTerm == '') {
            var counter = 0;
            return people.filter(function(person) {
                if(counter < 2) {
                    counter ++;
                    return person;
                }
            });


        } else {
            return people.filter(function(person) {
                return person.get('firstName').toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1 ||
                       person.get('lastName').toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1;
            });
        }
    }.property('content', 'searchTerm','content.@each')
});
```

Comment: It works, thx man ! also works if you remove first content and just keep coneten.@each.